# How to measure performance and maintainability of the system in UML class diagram?

Tags: performance, uml, class-diagram, maintainability

I am now doing a UML test section, I understand what does performance and maintainability mean in general, but I don't understand how to rate them with UML class diagram.
The test question is:

> Consider the model depicted with the UML class diagram in the
>   following figure.

[image: The figure]

> Now consider a change of the model in terms of adding a subtotal
>   attribute (with the value article.getPrice()*quantity) and a get
>   method for it to the OrderLine class, and using it within getTotal().
>   What effect would this change have on the non-functional properties of
>   the system?
>
> A) worse performance of Order.getTotal(), better maintainability of the system
>
> B) better performance of Order.getTotal(), worse maintainability of the system
>
> C) no effect
>
> D) worse performance of Order.getTotal(), worse maintainability of the system
>
> E) better performance of Order.getTotal(), better maintainability of the system

The right answer here is A,
so please explain how to come to this answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Please draw a class diagram of the new situation and show it to me. Then, I will guide you further to the explanation you want.

Comment: You're not the first to struggle with bad examples from (bad) teachers :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintainability is better in scenario 2 because the encapsulation of OrderLine is improved (i.e. someone maintaining this code would thank you for **not** including logic that *should* be in OrderLine in Order instead).

Performance will be worse in scenario 2 since the (probable) compiler optimisations will mean that both *getArticle().getPrice()* and *getQuantity()* calls will **optimise** to the same as *directly accessing* the *price* and *quantity* variables in memory (being *primitives* these will be on the **stack**, assuming these *get* methods are simple accessors), whereas *subTotal()* will not optimise in this way since it is not a simple accessor (i.e. it contains logic itself) which means you are therefore forcing a traversal to the **heap** (where the OrderLine instances live) in order to get access to the *price* variables. *The stack is much faster to access than the heap.*

So in scenario 1, the price and quantity variables are accessed directly on the stack by the loop in Order. In scenario 2 you're forcing a reference/pointer traverse to the heap due to calling the subTotal() method, which takes time to process, albeit a minute difference in reality for today's CPU and memory bus speeds.

Stack = primitives (i.e. price, quantity) and references/pointers.
Heap = objects (i.e. Order, OrderLine and Article instances).

Comment: Actually, I'm not entirely sure that *getArticle().getPrice()* will optimise to resolve directly to the *price* on the stack. It may just give you a location on the heap for the Article which it traverses to, to then get the *price*. Humm. I think it depends on the compiler.

Comment: In fact, I'm wrong in the above answer. getArticle() will return a reference to an object on the heap. getPrice() then returns a value from the stack.  So, in other words, you have to go to the heap to get price from Article in both scenarios 1 and 2. Moreover, because with scenario 2 you're going to the heap one fewer times than in scenario 1, I'd think scenario 2 would be better performing?

Comment: Anyway -- I'm struggling to see why A is correct. I've left the answer up, wrong or not, to discuss.

Comment: Having done some tests on this (C#, .NET 4.7.2) I can confirm basically no difference between the two in terms of performance. This might be my CLR/compiler optimisations etc. I'd need to write it in C and give it a go, but from a practical standpoint, I'm struggling with A.

Comment: Excellent work! Regarding the maintainability, I agree with your answer and regarding performance, your experiment is the key. I think the performance depends too much on language, environment etc. to give an answer.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl agreed!

Answer (score 0):

I think that C is the right answer. The original situation is that `Order` accesses `OrderLine` to get the quantity and via the same object access to `Article` for the price. With those values it performs a multiplication (within a summing cycle). Now in the new situation it calls `subtotal` from `Order` which itself has to access `Article` for the price and that will return the result of a multiplication. So from a performance view there is absolutely no difference. From a maintainability view the `subtotal` might be a better approach, though it's advantage to hide a multiplication doesn't seem to be notable anyway.

Comment: The maintainability thing is linked to the better encapsulation in the second scenario I think.

Comment: @muszeo Probably. But I'D regard this as marginal. Once again a teacher with bad examples to learn from.